# How to match left alignment of equations in math mode outside and inside an array?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations, arrays

My code is shown below, every equation is left aligned, my problem is that the equations inside the array enviroment seem to be indented. How can I align **all** the equations to the same vertical line?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10 pt,two column,fleqn]{article}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2.5cm}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{nopageno,array,graphicx,amsbsy,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,MnSymbol,wasysym,bbold}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|{#1}\rangle}

\begin{document}
\[S_z\ket{\pm} = \pm\frac{\hbar}{2}\ket{\pm}\]
\[S_{\pm} = S_x\pm S_y\]
  \[\begin{array}{ll}
    S_z = \dfrac{\hbar}{2}(\ket{+}\bra{+} + \ket{-}\bra{-}) \mbox{\hspace{10mm}}& \ket{s_z,\pm} = \ket{\pm}\\ \\
    S_y = \dfrac{-i\hbar}{2}(\ket{+}\bra{-} - \ket{-}\bra{+}) &\ket{s_y,\pm} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{+}\pm i\ket{-})\\ \\ 
    S_x = \dfrac{\hbar}{2}(\ket{+}\bra{-} + \ket{-}\bra{+}) & \ket{s_x,\pm} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{+}\pm\ket{-})\\
  \end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@{}` as in `\begin{array}{@{}ll}`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10 pt,two column,fleqn]{article}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2.5cm}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{nopageno,array,graphicx,amsbsy,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,MnSymbol,wasysym,bbold,physics}
%\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|{#1}\rangle}

\begin{document}
\[S_z\ket{\pm} = \pm\frac{\hbar}{2}\ket{\pm}\]
\[S_{\pm} = S_x\pm S_y\]
  \[\begin{array}{@{}ll}
    S_z = \dfrac{\hbar}{2}(\ket{+}\bra{+} + \ket{-}\bra{-}) \mbox{\hspace{10mm}}& \ket{s_z,\pm} = \ket{\pm}\\ \\
    S_y = \dfrac{-i\hbar}{2}(\ket{+}\bra{-} - \ket{-}\bra{+}) &\ket{s_y,\pm} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{+}\pm i\ket{-})\\ \\
    S_x = \dfrac{\hbar}{2}(\ket{+}\bra{-} + \ket{-}\bra{+}) & \ket{s_x,\pm} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{+}\pm\ket{-})\\
  \end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note, instead of defining `\ket` and `\bra`, you may opt to use `physics` package that offers many enhancements.

Answer (score 3):

You *never* want to use consecutive display math environments.

Use `align`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,twocolumn,fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,braket}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
S_z\ket{\pm} &= \pm\frac{\hbar}{2}\ket{\pm} \\
S_{\pm} &= S_x\pm S_y \\
S_z &= \dfrac{\hbar}{2}(\ket{+}\bra{+} + \ket{-}\bra{-})
  & \ket{s_z,\pm} &= \ket{\pm} \\
S_y &= \dfrac{-i\hbar}{2}(\ket{+}\bra{-} - \ket{-}\bra{+})
  & \ket{s_y,\pm} &= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{+}\pm i\ket{-}) \\
S_x &= \dfrac{\hbar}{2}(\ket{+}\bra{-} + \ket{-}\bra{+})
  & \ket{s_x,\pm} &= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{+}\pm\ket{-})
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've loaded the `braket` package for `\ket`.

Alternatively, if you don't want the first equation to be aligned at the equals with the following ones, there's `gather` and `aligned`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,twocolumn,fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,braket}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
S_z\ket{\pm} = \pm\frac{\hbar}{2}\ket{\pm} \\
\!\begin{aligned}
S_{\pm} &= S_x\pm S_y \\
S_z &= \dfrac{\hbar}{2}(\ket{+}\bra{+} + \ket{-}\bra{-})
  & \ket{s_z,\pm} &= \ket{\pm} \\
S_y &= \dfrac{-i\hbar}{2}(\ket{+}\bra{-} - \ket{-}\bra{+})
  & \ket{s_y,\pm} &= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{+}\pm i\ket{-}) \\
S_x &= \dfrac{\hbar}{2}(\ket{+}\bra{-} + \ket{-}\bra{+})
  & \ket{s_x,\pm} &= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\ket{+}\pm\ket{-})
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]